# Webpack 5 font asset issue, no error but no font either

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I'm attempting to use a @font-face declaration in my scss file.

The correct CSS rule is getting applied so the font-face declaration seems fine. The path is getting resolved as well so that's no issue. And, webpack throws no errors so it doesn't appear to be any kind of a loader issue. But in the end, the font is still not being rendered by the browser. ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcvgZ.png))

As of Webpack 5, [the documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/) states that you can declare in the rules "type: 'asset/resource'" to correctly load an asset such as a font or an image. It's working for the image I loaded, but not for the font.

CSS:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Yusei Magic', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('./assets/fonts/yusei-magic/YuseiMagic-Regular.ttf')
        format('truetype');
}
```

Webpack config:

```js
module: {
...
        rules: [
            ...
            {
                test: /\.ttf$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
        ],
    },
```

Comment: It might be worth trying with a `.woff`/`.woff2` font as I've had issues with corrupted `.ttf` fonts before when trying to load it as a webfont.

Comment: Thanks! I can try it. Although it should work for both. And, it's worth noting that I use this exact `.ttf` file in other projects using CSS-in-JS, with no issue.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab? Perhaps a 404 for the font?

Comment: Hmm. I just checked and I'm not seeing any 404's, but also not any requests or anything in the fonts tab of the network tab.

Comment: @gittenger instead of writing "solved" in the title - please mark the most helpful answer as accepted (even if it's yours). I've reverted the change to your question for you - but you'll need to give the tick yourself.

Comment: Cool, thank you. It says I can mark my own answer in two days. I'm new to asking questions on here. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're defining a `@font-face` declaration, on the `font-family` property, you must only write a string indicating how you will reference the font in your later styles.

In other words, I erroneously included "sans-serif" after "Yusei Magic" on the `font-family` property. This didn't throw an error, but it's incorrect CSS and thus was the source of my error. Thanks for anyone who chimed in!

Answer (score 3):

As you use `url('./assets/fonts/yusei-magic/YuseiMagic-Regular.ttf')` in your css which is a relative path, in order to webpack can resolve these kind of relative paths in your CSS files you should use `resolve-url-loader` as the following configuration in rules array in your `webpack.config.js` file:

```
other loaders ...

{
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/, // styles files
    use: ["style-loader",'css-loader' ,'resolve-url-loader', {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true, 
      }
    }],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/, // to import images and fonts
    loader: "file-loader",
  },
```

the first one for loading css/scss files with resolved URLs and the second one for loading fonts (and of course this pattern also load images too :)).

Answer (score 2):

Since the font is referenced by the css function `url()`, the responsible Webpack loaders needs to be added too.

If not installed:

```
npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader
```

The rules stack should look like this:

```
 rules: [
   ...
   {
     test: /\.css$/i,
     use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
   },
   {
     test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
     type: 'asset/resource',
   },
   ...
 ]
```

Details can be found [here (loading-css)](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-css) and [here (loading-fonts)](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-fonts).

`css-loader` interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()` and will resolve them.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm already using css-loader and sass-loader. Sorry, I didn't include the full text of the config file as I didn't want to bloat the question. But my scss and css files are loading and applying styles correctly. The only issue I'm having is the font not being loaded in the url() declaration. I referenced the exact documentation you've linked in the OP.

Comment: I was working on integrating the fonts and accidentally chained `style-loader` and `MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader`. Be aware to use them appropriately like this `isDevMode ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader`.